# Courier-imap with sendmail setup: why is my IMAP inbox empty?

Tags: imap, sendmail

I've successfully installed sendmail, but when I connect to the Courier IMAP server via Outlook, the Inbox is listed as empty. When I check the inbox with Alpine locally on the server, it has content though. Why? I do see files with content in /var/mail . Is that not where Courier-imap checks for mail?

The setup is pretty clean - I run Ubuntu 12.04 on AWS, have installed sendmail and courier-imap. sendmail was configured with `sendmailconfigure` and it works well to both send and receive mail. The problem is with courier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had some configuration issues. When I followed [this guide](http://wiki.kartbuilding.net/index.php/Secure_Outgoing_SMTP_via_Postfix,_Courier,_TLS_and_SASL) point by point, I got it working:

> ### Secure Outgoing SMTP via Postfix, Courier, TLS and SASL
>
> - **OK. First off: apt-get**
>
> ```
> apt-get install postfix-tls libsasl2-2 sasl2-bin libsasl2-modules
> ```
>
> Main Website used for Config: http://www.falkotimme.com/howtos/perfect_setup_debian_sarge/index.php
>
> Secondard Website - however uses a different Auth file: http://www.tribulaciones.org/docs/postfix-sasl-tls-howto.html
>
> More Good Info & a SIMPLE WAY TO OVERCOME CHROOT -> http://wiki.ev-15.com/debian:mail_system
>
> **A lot of the following is old and not required in debian squeeze:**
>
> - **Configing:**
>
> /etc/postfix/main.cf
> /etc/postfix/sasl/smtpd.conf
> /etc/postfix/ssl/* - tls certs
>
> ```
> 1. 
> # SASL Support
> smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
> smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
> smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
> broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
> smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination
> ```
>
> ```
> 2.
> # SASL Auth
> vi /etc/postfix/sasl/smtpd.conf
> pwcheck_method: saslauthd
> mech_list: plain login
> ```
>
> ```
> 3.
> # TLS Certs
> mkdir /etc/postfix/ssl
> cd /etc/postfix/ssl/
> openssl genrsa -des3 -rand /etc/hosts -out smtpd.key 1024
> chmod 600 smtpd.key
> openssl req -new -key smtpd.key -out smtpd.csr
> openssl x509 -req -days 3650 -in smtpd.csr -signkey smtpd.key -out smtpd.crt
> openssl rsa -in smtpd.key -out smtpd.key.unencrypted
> mv -f smtpd.key.unencrypted smtpd.key
> openssl req -new -x509 -extensions v3_ca -keyout cakey.pem -out cacert.pem -days 3650
>
>
> # TLS Config in /etc/postfix/main.cf
> # Moving onto TLS on its own.
> smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
> smtp_use_tls = yes
> smtpd_use_tls = yes
> smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
> smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/ssl/smtpd.key
> smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/ssl/smtpd.crt
> smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/ssl/cacert.pem
> smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
> smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
> smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
> tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
> ```
>
> ```
> vi /etc/postfix/main.cf
> //add in
> smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
> //Then try and send emails via smtpd
> ```
>
> - **Restart Postfix**
>
> Now continuing onto Auth
> Because postfix runs chrooted - need to move the /var/run dir
>
> ```
> mkdir -p /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd
> rm -fr /var/run/saslauthd
> ```
>
> **Edit /etc/default/saslauthd**
>
> ```
> Remove # in front of START=yes
> Add the line PARAMSOPTIONS="-m /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd"
> ```
>
> **Edit /etc/init.d/saslauthd**
>
> ```
> Add a # to dir=`dpkg-statoverride --list $PWDIR`
> Add in dir=".... below the PIDFILE entry
> #dir=`dpkg-statoverride --list $PWDIR`
> Change PWDIR and PIDFILE to the following:
> PWDIR="/var/spool/postfix/var/run/${NAME}"
> PIDFILE="${PWDIR}/saslauthd.pid"
> dir="root sasl 755 ${PWDIR}"
> //change to:
> createdir root sasl 755 $RUN_DIR
> ```
>
> - **Save & Close**
> - **restart saslauthd**
> - **/etc/init.d/saslauthd start**
> - **MAKE SURE TO ADJUST FIREWALL - OPEN UP PORT 111 Locally**
>
> #### Debugging and testing
>
> ```
> user@otherserver:~$ telnet mail.burkesys.com 25
> Trying 78.47.9.122...
> Connected to mail.burkesys.com.
> Escape character is '^]'.
> 220 mail.burkesys.com ESMTP Postfix (Debian/GNU)
> ehlo localhost
> 250-mail.burkesys.com
> 250-PIPELINING
> 250-SIZE 20000000
> 250-ETRN
> 250-STARTTLS
> 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
> 250-8BITMIME
> 250 DSN
> ```
>
> After connecting via telnet, type "ehlo localhost" and watch for the "STARTTLS" line. This *should* show up.
>
> Of course o2 have started filtering external traffic over port 25, and filterting out the starttls which makes life difficult for thunderbird. See: http://markmail.org/message/v5uofqpx5l5pu4rm Just as well I have port 587 open for use with a nice iptable rule:
>
> ```
> iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 587 -j DNAT --to ip.address:25
> iptables -t nat -L
> iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING 1
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Actually `sendmail` by default stores mail by default in `~/mail` (IE the current user's home directory + `mail`) while Courier without modification is looking in `~/Maildir` which is where Postfix and QMAIL deliver mail.

You have to modify the courier `imapd` file in `/etc/courier/imapd` to get it to work. But even then your upstream mail program also has to be modified. (Squirrel Mail, Roundcube).